# Akka 2.1 exception handling (Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

I have a supervising Akka actor which uses a router to forward messages to worker actors.

I have a class which wraps the supervisor and when I call a method on that class it "asks" the supervisor to do something and then I use `Await.result(theFuture)` to wait for the result (I cannot continue without the result).

If the workers throw an exception, I want to restart the worker which threw the exception, and I want the exception to be caught by the code which calls the wrapper class.

I passed a `OneForOneStrategy` to the router constructor, which returns `RESTART` in the case of an `Exception`.  In the `postRestart` method of the worker, I log the restart, so I can validate that the worker is actually restarted.

When the worker throws an exception, it gets restarted, but the exception disappears.  The `Future` which is the result of asking the supervisor, contains an exception, but it is a `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException`, which is thrown after just 5 seconds rather than 20 seconds, which is the implicit timeout that I have lingering around.  The exception actually occurs less than a second after the worker starts.

**Question 1:** how can I get the exception from the worker in the code which calls my wrapper class?

Also, the receive method of the worker is like this:

```
def receive = {
    case r: Request => 
        val response = ??? //throws an exception sometimes
        sender ! response
}
```

Something is logging the exception to the console, but it isn't my code.  The stack trace is:

```
[ERROR] [02/11/2013 21:34:20.093] [MySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9]  
[akka://MySystem/user/MySupervisor/MyRouter/$a] Something went wrong!
    at myApp.Worker.$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Source.scala:169)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Line 169 of `Source.scala` is the line `val response = ???` shown in the listing of the `receive` method above.

**Question 2:** who is logging that exception to the console, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Q2 : see ActorLogging.

Comment: Q1 : why not using Try ? (scala 2.10)

Comment: @twillouer I am using Try -> myFuture.value.get gives a Try, which in this case is a Failure containing the timeout exception.

Comment: why do not return a Try ? like sender ! Try(...) ?

Comment: You mean catch the exception in the worker and return a Failure?  If that is what you mean, then I was hoping to avoid catching exceptions in workers, if possible.

Comment: @twillouer Section 5.3 of the Akka 2.1 manual talks about logging, but I cannot see anything that talks about default logging of exceptions.  Do you have any more hints? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
try somethingThatCanFail() catch {
    case e: Exception => sender ! Status.Failure(e); throw e
}
```

The "tell failure" causes the caller to get a Failure containing the exception.  Throwing "e" causes the oneForOneStrategy to be called which restarts the worker.

2)

> It is the actor system itself that logs the failure, and the only way
>   to quiet it down is to filter out things by creating and configuring
>   your own LoggingAdapter as described here
>   http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/logging.html There is a
>   ticket for changing this
>   https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2824 but it is targeted
>   for Akka 2.2

Answered by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/fenCvYu3HYE

Answer (score 0):

In order to be notified of one of your children failing, you need to

- First `watch` the child
- Then you will be sent a `Terminated()` when the actor dies with a reference to it.

Something like:

```
class ParentActor extends Actor {
   // this is sample of how to watch for death of one of your children 
   val childActor = context.actorOf(Props[SomeService], "SomeService")
   val dyingChild = context.watch(context.actorOf(childActor))

   def receive = {
     case Terminated(`dyingChild`) =>
        println("dyingChild died") 
     case Terminated(terminatedActor) => 
        println(s"This child just died $terminatedActor")
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't answer either question.